# Custom CKEditor TypeError: this.props.editor.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, node-modules

I'm using the following JSX code with a custom CKEditor that I built using the [online-builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) When I add this editor to my node modules and try to use it like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-custom';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'

const editorConfiguration = {
    toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|' ]
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 5 from online builder in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    config={ editorConfiguration }
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
                    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    } }
                    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
                    } }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I get an error stating that `TypeError: this.props.editor.create is not a function`. Is there some step that I am apparently missing? The help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of research online and trying to figure out where the custom build went wrong it turned out to be the most simple solution ever! In my custom build's `src` folder where the `ckeditor.js` file is located (containing the custom build before being built) I noticed at the bottom of the file it looked something like this `export default { Editor, Watchdog };` 
 Seeing this I immediately knew the solution was to **import the custom editor as a named import**. If you import it as a default import then you will not have any of the features of the editor but rather the entire export as shown above. Simple solution change the line that says `import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-custom';` to `import {Editor as ClassicEditor} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-custom';` and now it will import the way it was meant to be imported.
The interesting part about this, is that if you do not add Watchdog to your custom build (using the [online-builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)) then it should be imported as a default import as it will export as follows `export default Editor;`